# Only me and admin able to access sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-collection

My site has one library and various folders in it which are given access through various groups and different permission level. Yesterday I got to encounter this scenario that no user from any group is able to access the site though read/edit permissions are given to the user through the group he belongs to.

I, as a site collection admin provided read permission to a group(JapanCAO) on library and its folders and sub folders. Later I added my colleague in that group. Now on pulling up the group's permissions, home and folder url's have read access. But while my colleague navigates to the url's, he gets message

> "Sorry, you don't have access to this page".

Now I reversed the scenario. I set my colleague as admin and removed him from the group(JapanCAO). I removed myself from admin list, and added my name into the group(JapanCAO). Strangely I am able to access the home url and also all url's having read access for the group(JapanCAO).

First I thought this issue might be because of the multiple copies of master pages i created some days back. but on resetting the changes to site definition, the issue still exists.

Comment: Go to site permissions. click on magnifier icon (check permissions). provide your colleagues id, and check his permissions assigned. similar try for another scenario where you removed yourself from SC admin group. and then check your permissions.. Also site might not have permissions inherited ON.. verify and confirm

Comment: Yes the permissions are same for my colleague and me(me not included in SC admin). Some folders have been set unique permissions and some inherit parent permissions.

Comment: Is there any extra group you are part of? You will see all permissions direct and from group

Comment: No. I removed myself from all groups and i got access denied for site home page. then from my colleagues machine i added myself into the group(JapanCAO). and now i am able to access only the pages having access set to JapanCAO group.

Comment: What type of site collection? Publishing or team or team with publishing feature on?

Comment: Its publishing.

Comment: When I remove all my access and I try to access home page, error thrown is "Tell us why do you need access to this page". However if given permission to one of my colleague, the error is "You don't have access to this page"

Answer (score 0):

It caused due to changes made in Master page. There are 2 types of master pages; seattle.html and seattle.master.
On changing master page I set seattle.html as default and forgot to set seattle.master as default.
I did check this on website and it showed both .html and .master were default master pages. however through designer I encountered that .master is not set as default master page.

The issue hence resolved.
Thanks for your help  guys.